# Elasticsearch reserve node

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 4-nodes elasticsearch cluster (1 of them is client, es 1.3.5).

It works fine most of time, but sometimes on peaks gone out of resources.
Can i add any reserve node in cluster that will be enabled only when peaks occured (1-2 day in months) and will be disabled all other time? Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no notion of backup/standby/reserve node. You monitor the cluster activity and you start a new node when the peak happens. If you would have used a newer version you could have used Marvel (the monitoring part) and Watcher (the alerting part) to get notified on the peaks. At that point you could have started the new node.

There are also examples of watches that alert you in case of high memory or cpu usage: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/watching-marvel-data.html#watching-memory-usage

Comment: I can use marvel and watchers with 1.3, but problem not in monitoring)

if i start a new node i should update all nodes config to add this node into discovery, replicas number, wait while it will receive all data, right? but what if i will have node already added into discovery and it will be shutdown?

Comment: You cannot. Watcher needs at least version 1.5. If the node already in the discovery is shutdown shouldn't be any problem. The discovery part is for new nodes joining so that they can learn the cluster structure. The new nodes theoretically need only one node from all those available to learn who else is in the cluster and where.

Comment: ok, thanks. one more question. what if i configure one client node for load balancing and 4 worker nodes (3 replicas, 1 shard), than shutdown one of them. should i change replicas number to 2 (it will be yellow i think)? and change again to 3 when enabled

Comment: There is a thing called `auto_expand_replicas` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings - that you can se to `0-all` and the replica sizing is done automatically based on the number of nodes.